# How to separate benzyl alcohol and meta-cresol

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, precipitation, distillation

Benzyl alcohol and meta-cresol boiling point's are not so different, the fractional distillation will be very difficult, what can i do for separate this two composites ?

Comment: I guess extraction with NaOH in water would be OK

Answer (score 2):

Your observation on the boiling points is correct.

Take a look at the **melting points** instead: the m.p. of benzyl alcohol is -15 °C, while the m.p. of m-cresol is 11 °C. You might want to cool down the mixture and see whether you can see some enrichment.